# How do I set the Grid.ColumnSpan on an item that is generated through an ItemsControl's ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a bunch of items that is generated through an ItemsControl's Itemsource. These are contained within a UniformGrid. Now I want to set some of these items to a greater Grid.ColumnSpan based on some condition.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FatRowItemTemplate}"
                          IsTabStop="False">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding Columns}"
                                     Width="{Binding ItemWidth}"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            </ItemsControl>
```

The FatRowItemTemplate is just a Border with a text field contained within.

I have tried to set the Border Grid.ColumnSpan in the Template but that does not seem to work. How can I change the ColumnSpan on these items?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? There is no Grid involved anywhere, so setting Grid.ColumnSpan would have no effect.

Comment: I'm using a UniformGrid for these items and I should be able to set the Grid.ColumnSpan on my generated items according to this if I understand it correctly?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/uniformgrid

Section - Sized Children

Comment: "The UWP UniformGrid now inherits from Grid " = won't work in wpf.

Comment: @Andy What does that mean? I don't quite follow.

Comment: In wpf you could consider wrappanel. Adjust width
What happens if an item is last in row and spans 2 items?

Comment: "Won't work in wpf" was unclear?

Comment: @Andy So I Can set spans on items in WrapPanels? Didn't see that feature

Comment: @Andy It was clear that you said it won't work but don't understand why.

Comment: You can adjust WIDTH. Make an item double the width of others.

Comment: It won't work because wpf is not uwp.

Comment: Both have xaml, so the controls might seem like they're kind of the same thing but they are totally different technologies and totally different source code for those controls. A WPF UniformGrid is a completely different thing to a UWP ( or MAUI ) UniformGrid.

Comment: @Andy Hmm... Can see if I can get it to work that way, ah well thanks for letting me know uniformgrid don't work

Comment: You're welcome. I try and help.  Think about what a jagged row will look like though. If you could have one.